# How to use a multiply function to execute an exponent function?

Tags: javascript, exponent

So I had a task to create an add function. Then create a multiply function that does not use operators and uses the add function. Now I need to use this multiply function to create a power(exponent) function. This is my attempt so far:

```js
function add(a, b){
   return a + b;
}
// console.log(add(6, 4))
    
    
function multiply(first, second){
    let i = 0;
    let answer = 0;
    while(i < second){
        answer += add(first, 0);
        i += 1;
    }
    return answer;

}
// let m = multiply(10, 4)
// console.log(m);
    
    
function power(x, n){
    let i = 0;
    let answer = multiply(x, x);
    let total = 1;
    while(i < n){
        total += multiply(x, answer)
        i += 1;
     }
     return total;
}
let p = power(2, 4)
console.log(p)
```

I seem to be stuck here because any changes I make have not been helpful. Any tips on this one?

Comment: What does "any changes I make have not been helpful" mean?

Comment: As in, all the changes I have made so far have not reached the desired outcome.

Comment: Seriously, what does "all the changes I have made so far have not reached the desired outcome" mean? I'm after exact changes, what didn't work, how you knew, what errors, what you wanted, etc. Vague descriptions of problems are not terribly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you did there is multiplying n with x^3, and then add 1 to it.
Because total equals 1. And answer equals x^2, then multiply(x,answer) will give you x^3. You add x^3 to your total in every iteration, thus total will give you 1+(n*x^3)

I suggest you try this one :

```
function power(x, n){
    let i = 0;
    let answer = 1;
    while(i < n){
        answer = multiply(x, answer)
        i += 1;
     }
     return answer;
}
```

Comment: AHH! Thanks so much, seeing it here it looks much more simple than what I was trying to do. I have been staring at the computer for too long...

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct function:

```
function power(x, n){
    let i = 1;
    let total = x;
    while(i < n){
        total = multiply(total,x)
        i += 1;
     }
     return total;
}
```

You were adding the results of each multiplication, you actually only want to get the final multiplication result. Also, the indexes were wrong.